# Check collision between 2 arrays

Tags: java, arrays, swing, collision-detection, area

I have 2 arrays of images. The image is converted into array based on transparency.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usEDD.png)

For example this 8x8 image below is the transparency array

```
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

I don't know how to check the collision between 2 of these arrays so i do not have any code because i dont know where to start. I dont want to use area object because it takes to much time to make image to area object.

**Important**: they also have their own x, y, width and height to check.

Comment: What do you mean by "*they also have their own x, y, width and height to check.*"? What ix `x` and `y` in this context? And you want to compare different sized arrays? Please share an example where you show your input, your expected output from that input and also explain why this input results in the specified output. And finally whats a "collision" in your context? Two arrays having a a value <> 0 in the same spot?

Comment: The transperency map belongs to an entity object in my game engine. I am trying to check collision between 2 images, I DO NOT WANT TO USE AREA as it takes to much time to convert from `Image` to `Area`. X is the entity X, and so on

Comment: In Java Swing, collision detection happens between rectangles and circles.  The `java.awt.Rectangle` class has `contains` and `intersects` methods to detect collisions.  A circle intersect check, which you have to code, is an object is less than radius away.   Sprite drawing should be based on an underlying logical model.  The view draws the model.  Collision detection takes place in the model.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc you do have a point, but to create rigid body physics, i want to get accurate collision detection, even `java.awt.geom.Area` has `contains` and `intersects` method. But it takes too long to convert an image to area. And again i want accurate collision detection

Comment: There should be absolutely no "convert an image to area".  That's why you have a logical model.  If you have an 8 x 8 sprite, you define a `java.awt.Rectangle` with a width and height of 8.  When your view draws, you get the `Rectangle` instance and draw the sprite in the x, y position of the `Rectangle`.  Your view draws the logical model.  Period.  Nothing else.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc **accurate collision detection**. Im not only going to be using an 8x8 sprite, its just for the example.